# Handouts for oral presentation, templates?

Tags: templates, handout

I'm trying to create handouts for an oral presentation with pictures but we can't do a PowerPoint. Is there a simple template I can mess with? The only document class I have experience with is article.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you know the ``beamer`` class? It's a great document class to make LaTeX presentations. There are a lot of ``beamer`` templates online, for example [on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tagged/presentation).

Comment: With beamer you can ask for handouts (last, complete slide only), and with e.g. pdfjam you can create handouts in 2×3 a page from the PDFs. Present with your favorite PDF viewer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple but elegant template to start:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Foo}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}
\usetheme{Madrid} % or  Warsaw, Berkeley, metropolis, ...
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}{Bah} More bah \end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Baz} More baz \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Basically you only have to add  `\begin{frame}{...} ...\end{frame}` for each new slide and then change the dots by a title and some content (of course, it could be tables, graphs , lists, etc. )

Run `texdoc beamer` to see the Beamer User Guide in pdf. You have a lot of possibilities here. There are also plenty of examples of Beamer presentations in this site to make almost many more complex things, but remember the KISS principle (keep it simply, sir).